# Como colocar uma imagem com largura total em site?

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber como faço pra colocar uma imagem em largura total em um *site.*. Estou fazendo um *site* e gostaria de saber..

Obrigado

Comment: Matheus, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Sua pergunta foi fechada porque já existe outra questão que responde exatamente a ela. Caso discorde disso, você pode adicionar um comentário e argumentar ou editar sua pergunta para esclarecer exatamente o que deseja. Fique à vontade para fazer novas perguntas ou responder no site. Abraço!

Comment: Expandindo o comentário do @utluiz, certifique-se de pesquisar o site *antes* de abrir uma nova pergunta, e forneça todos os *detalhes necessários* do seu código quando escrever uma nova pergunta. E, igualmente, bem-vindo ao SOPT :)